# Is it possible to implement Python code-completion in TextMate?

Tags: python, autocomplete, text-editor, textmate

[PySmell](http://github.com/orestis/pysmell/tree/master) seems like a good starting point.

I think it should be possible, PySmell's `idehelper.py` does a majority of the complex stuff, it should just be a case of giving it the current line, offering up the completions (the bit I am not sure about) and then replacing the line with the selected one.

```
>>> import idehelper
>>> # The path is where my PYSMELLTAGS file is located:
>>> PYSMELLDICT = idehelper.findPYSMELLDICT("/Users/dbr/Desktop/pysmell/")
>>> options = idehelper.detectCompletionType("", "" 1, 2, "", PYSMELLDICT)
>>> completions = idehelper.findCompletions("proc", PYSMELLDICT, options)
>>> print completions
[{'dup': '1', 'menu': 'pysmell.pysmell', 'kind': 'f', 'word': 'process', 'abbr': 'process(argList, excluded, output, verbose=False)'}]
```

It'll never be perfect, but it would be extremely useful (even if just for completing the stdlib modules, which should never change, so you wont have to constantly regenerate the PYSMELLTAGS file whenever you add a function)

---

Progressing! I have the utter-basics of completion in place - barely works, but it's close..

I ran `python pysmells.py /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/*.py -O /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pysmell/PYSMELLTAGS`

Place the following in a TextMate bundle script, set "input: entire document", "output: insert as text", "activation: key equivalent: alt+esc", "scope selector: source.python"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from pysmell import idehelper

CUR_WORD = os.environ.get("TM_CURRENT_WORD")

cur_file = os.environ.get("TM_FILEPATH")
orig_source = sys.stdin.read()
line_no = int(os.environ.get("TM_LINE_NUMBER"))
cur_col = int(os.environ.get("TM_LINE_INDEX"))

# PYSMELLS is currently in site-packages/pysmell/
PYSMELLDICT = idehelper.findPYSMELLDICT("/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pysmell/blah")
options = idehelper.detectCompletionType(cur_file, orig_source, line_no, cur_col, "", PYSMELLDICT)
completions = idehelper.findCompletions(CUR_WORD, PYSMELLDICT, options)

if len(completions) > 0:
    new_word = completions[0]['word']
    new_word = new_word.replace(CUR_WORD, "", 1) # remove what user has already typed
    print new_word
```

Then I made a new python document, typed "import urll" and hit alt+escape, and it completed it to "import urllib"!

As I said, it's entirely a work-in-progress, so don't use it yet..

---

*Last update:*

orestis has integrated this into the PySmell project's code! Any further fiddling will happen [on github](http://github.com/orestis/pysmell/tree/master)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: I've actually took your code above and integrated into a command. It will properly show a completion list for you to choose.

You can grab it here: http://github.com/orestis/pysmell/tree/master (hit download and do python setup.py install). It's rough but it works. - please report any errors on http://code.google.com/p/pysmell/

--

Hi, I'm the developer of PySmell. I also use a Mac, so if you can send me an email (contact info is in the source code) with your progress so far, I can try to integrate it :)

Oh BTW it's called PySmell - no trailing 's' :)

Comment: I had recently noticed the TextMate-related commits on the github project. I thought the code looked familiar, but I thought it was a coincidence.. :D

Answer (score 4):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for but it might be able to get you started:

[Using TextMate with Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/TextMate)

They appear to be somewhat Django specific but some snippets may assist with your needs.  You also may be able to build on top of that with PySmells.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but you can give it a try: http://mtod.org/tempy

Answer (score 0):

In TextMate PHP has a simple auto-completion in form of hardcoded set of function names. Sounds as ugly as PHP, but in practice it's good enough to be useful.